# Override protocol method not implemented in superclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

I have a superclass in a framework that implements an Objective-C protocol with optional methods. The superclass does not implement these optional methods. In the project that uses this framework, I would like to implement these methods in my subclass. However, I'm getting errors from Swift. Is there a better way to do this or a better design in the framework?

Note: Please keep in mind that the SuperClass is in an XCFramework and the SubClass was inside the application where the created XCFramework was imported.

```swift
    import UIKit
    class SuperClass: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {}  // This will be inside an XCFramework

    class SubClass: SuperClass {  

        override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { // Error: Method does not override any method from its superclass
        print("test")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the code snippet directly in the question, not as a screenshot! This will make it easier for everyone to help.

Comment: `override` is only used when you are replacing the implementation of the super class in the subclass. If the super doesn't have this method, then simply delete the keyword `override` and declare the function

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin. For some reason it doesn't work correctly when the override keyword is deleted. Please keep in mind that the SuperClass is in an XCFramework and the SubClass was inside the application where the created XCFramework was imported.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more of the code and explain how and where you are using it. I have a feeling you are trying to use an instance of the superClass or passing the subclass into a function that down casts it, or something along those lines